# sf2 php command-line issues for deployment @OVH

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, command-line

Hi there,

I am facing a quite annoying issue.

Situation
I would like to deploy symfony2 application in production on mutualized servers of OVH (pro). I got shell access (ssh), my database works fine and my files are online.

Issue
I cannot manage to make any php command line work. That is, for all major commandline:
- updating web directory : `php app/console assets:install web` 
- updating databases:      `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
- downloading composer:     `php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('http://getcomposer.org/installer'));"`
-etc...

I get parse errors such as:
 `syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in` 
or 
 `Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r` (that one was for composer download)

it seems a pretty common pb, however I couldn't manage to fix it :/

Any hints welcome!

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Which version of php are you running from the command line? Find out with `php -v`.

Comment: Hi Maerlyn. ey ! I am using php 4.4.9 ... Interesting fact actually. should be 5.4.21! how is that possible?

Comment: I mean: in my phpinfo(), it features PHP Version 5.4.21. it means that php doesn't point to the right version of php. but how should I fix this?

Comment: Talk to your hoster about using the same version in the command line as from the web. 4.4.9 is terribly obsolete.

Comment: Yes indeed. I have just sent a ticket. I shall come back to you if it was enough to solve the pb!

Comment: I believe you can not execute console script with php cli on a mutualized OVH server.
Take a look at ConsoleBundle or alternatives. It would allow you to execute symfony comand from your browser.

Comment: @oumlaote: your idea is nice. PHP can't be executed from the SSH connection but using ConsoleBundle or putting the commands in a plain PHP file executed from the right should deploy Symfony2 in the same way than from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

On ovh, you can choose witch php is used by altering the cmd line :

```
/usr/local/bin/php.ORIG.5_4 -> php.ORIG.5.4.6
/usr/local/bin/php.ORIG.5_3 -> php.ORIG.5.3.16
/usr/local/bin/php.ORIG.5_2 -> php.ORIG.5.2.17
/usr/local/bin/php -> php.ORIG.4
```

Comment: Hi tere, how about php5 and above ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular problem with deploying symfony2 project. I`m not sure that this is the case here, but my problem was with the cache. For some of the symfony2 console commands it uses cached paths, and if you have changed the location of the project this could cause the problem. It uses a cached path when trying to delete the cache :D so my suggestion is to go and delete manually the cache i app/cache.
Hope i helped

Comment: Hi gprusiiski,thanks for the hint. actually, I already deleted the cache manually (that is, with the good old rm -r shell command) up front.